# Hibernate Query (JPQL) turns new Object into persisted/managed object

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I do have a sample Java EE 7 EJB module containing 2 entities and a single stateless bean running on Wildfly 9.0.2 (Hibernate 4.3.10.Final) or 10.1.0 (Hibernate 5.0.10.Final)

- Entity Master has a simple `@Id` and `@OneToMany` relationship with Detail
- Entity Detail has a cascaded key using `@IdClass` and a `@ManyToOne` relationship with Master
- For convenience persistence unit uses builtin jboss/datasources/ExampleDS database (schema-generation=drop-and-create), so the DB-Tables are all empty at startup
- The stateless bean performs a simple query (nothing else). At flush/commit Hibernate inserts a row into Master table

This is the query

```
// setup new/unmanaged objects
Master m = new Master('masterkey');
Detail d = new Detail(m, 0);

em.createQuery("select count(d) from Detail d where d=:d")
  .setParameter("d", d)
  .getSingleResult()
```

Variations of the scenario lead to different errors

- If database already contains a Master row with key `'masterkey'`, the Stateless method fails with duplicate key error from database
- If the code (setup new objects and perform query) is duplicated the Stateless method fails with Hibernate error `A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [Master#masterkey]`

I found some workarounds in changing the query that's not my question. But why does Hibernate put new `Master` object into persistence context and subsequently insert it into database, it's just a query?

Comment: is this the entire transactional method? Is there anything else going on there?

Comment: Yes thats the entire transactional method, nothing else in the method

Comment: isnt that method part of another top-level transactional method?

Comment: At first I observed the behaviour in a complex JSF/Primefaces web application. To narrow the problem I built a sample maven project containing the persistence.xml, the two entity classes, the Id class, the stateless bean class and a `@Singleton @Startup` that performes the stateless method, nothing else. So the top level transactional method just calls the Stateless method.

Comment: This is the entire EJB project http://www.filedropper.com/hhhbug

Comment: Submitted a bug report to Hibernate https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12007